# Add-pnpClientSideWebPart not working as expected

Tags: web-part, pnp-powershell, modern-pages

I´m trying to add a WebPart to a modern page via PnP.

```
Add-PnPClientSideWebPart -Page "home.aspx" -DefaultWebPartType ContentRollup -Section 3 -Column 1 -WebPartProperties @{layoutid="List"}
```

It should be a list layout. But I´m getting a grid layout.

What is wrong?

Thanks!

Viktor

Answer (score 0):

You should put quotes around "layoutID" and try again.

Comment: The same behavior.